# How to Compare if a value is within the range or not?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with below structure:

[image]

Now i want to write a query in mysql or sql to see if a value is within the range or not.

Examples:
Suppose if a user passes **11** as input, now this lies **between SampleNo 0 and 13** so the query should fetch **100% as SNo**

Likewise if the user passes **13** then it should fetch **A as SNo** .

If a user passes **15** as input then this **lies between 13 and 25 SampleNo**, so the query should fetch **A as SNo** and so on

Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SNo
from m_table
WHERE SampleNo <= @variable
ORDER BY SampleNo DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select SNo from your_table where SampleNo <= InputValue Order by SampleNo DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: explain your answer

Comment: suppose InputValue is 11 so sample number <=11 means it will return records which have sampleNo less than or equal to 11 but "order by sampleNo Desc" will return max value row in first position and limit 1 will return only first record which has max value less than or equal to InputValue

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subquery for this :

```
select SNo
from your_table
where sampleNo = (select max(sampleNo)
    from your_table
    where sampleNo <= 11);
```

Comment: assumes that no duplicates for sampleno, but yeah good answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
SELECT sm1.* FROM mytable sm1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT max(SampleNo) FROM mytable WHERE SampleNo <= ?) as sm2
on sm1.SampleNo = sm2.SampleNo
```

Take care to replace `?` with the proper value.

however your question is title select value BETWEEN two others where as the sample you have provided shows the value that is immediately below it.

Also note that a WHERE IN (subquery) would only work if there aren't any duplicated values for SampleNo.

Comment: Why as this got a downvote? If there is a syntax error the usual practice is to point that out in a commen

Comment: will give 100% for 13

Comment: thanks for pointing that out fixed by adding the equal comparator.

Answer (score 0):

This is stored procedure, passed a parameter, and inside it, first it finds the max sampleno of entered number by user then, it finds the sno for the same.

```
create procedure dbo.sample @data int
as
select SNo
from samp
where sampleno = (select max(sampleno)
from samp
where samplemo <= @data);
go

exec dbo.sample @data=11
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it helps. Code only answers are frowned upon at StackOverflow generally speaking.

Comment: i av just made a stored procedure and passed a parameter and insidde it firsty i found the max sampleno of entered number by user then find out the sno for the same.

Comment: I put it in the answer (where it belongs) for you. If I said it wrong, please edit your answer and correct my error.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        select SNo
        from #TableName
        where SampleNo = (select max(SampleNo)from #TableName
        where SampleNo <= 15);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select SNo from tblname where N > SampleNo Order By SampleNo asc Limit 1
```

Replace tblname and N with Proper Value

Comment: ordering in ascending order will return `100%` in almost every situation as it's the first one that's the lowest SampleNo value